# How to get the length of a time vector in seconds?

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I load an audio file and get `sample` and `sampleRate` with

```
[sample, sampleRate] = audioread(audiofile);
```

I want to get the length of the audio in seconds, how do I proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having the sampleRate, the inverse of it is the sampling time.

```
Ts=1/sampleRate;
```

So the time vector for your sampled data would be

```
time=(0:(length(sample)-1))*Ts;
```

Comment: Reading the question, it doesn't seem the OP is interested in a vector, just the total length. So using your logic (and avoiding the built-in name `time`) we have `audioLength = length(sample)/sampleRate`.